# Culture is not supported when deserializing file

Tags: c#, deserialization, cultureinfo

I'm trying to deserialize a file that was serialized from a system with a foreign culture.
I am getting the following error, but I can't seem to get around it.
Any pointers appreciated.

> Culture is not supported. Parameter name: culture 3072 (0x0c00) is an
> invalid culture identifier.

Even trying to set the culture to any country does not change the error that culture 3072 is invalid.

```
var file = "C:\\myfile.blb"
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("el-GR"); //Adding or removing this line does NOT change the error.
var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
try
{
    var format = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    DataSet ds = format.Deserialize(fs) as DataSet;  //Exception thrown on THIS line
    ....
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `throw ex;` This line will reset the stack trace for the thrown Exception. You should keep it because it makes it much easier to find where an exception originated from. You can do this using `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`

Comment: Are you deserializing in .NET Framework, .NET Core, or .NET?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen FWIW, testing locally it doesn't work for me in .NET Core, .NET 6, *or* .NET Framework 4.8; I'm guessing it needs an additional OS culture installed?

Comment: Deserializing in .Net Framework

Comment: what if you change to `en-US`?

Comment: I think this is a fascinating problem (I'm pretty involved in serialization concerns), but... I'm not sure I can advise on any *simple* ways out of this hole. This is made even more acute because `BinaryFormatter` is pretty much hard dead in modern .NET, and `DataSet` is almost as bad and almost always best avoided. I realise this isn't an easy message to deliver (or receive), but: is it even remotely possible to change your serialization stack here? to something that involves simple POCO serialization using something like JSON, protobuf, or similar? This is only going to get worse...

Comment: Relevant? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172903/microsoft-sql-server-local-report-culture-is-not-supported-3072-is-invalide-cul

Comment: Using en-US gives the same error. But if I serialize a file on my PC it does work. Might be related to right-to-left culture of the foreign culture.

Comment: Note: el-GR is LCID 1032, not 3072; I've no idea what 3072 is - still looking (could it be a custom culture hacked into the registry?)

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks for the input. I can't change it easily, but in the long run it may have to happen. Any recommendations?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I have not installed any other cultures (that I know off). Also not sure what 3072 is.

Comment: @CameronCastillo I'm massively biased - I'm the author of protobuf-net which usually meets my serialization needs very well, but: Json.NET is also great

Comment: @CameronCastillo some googling suggests *possibly* a variant of en-SZ? anecdotal, but: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32602ff8-6902-499d-960a-f164583180e1/culturenotfoundexception-3072-0x0c00-is-an-invalid-culture-identifier

Comment: I know this won't solve your immediate problems, and it may not even be your own design here, but you shouldn't be using BinaryFormatter for anything beyond process-to-process transport. BinaryFormatter is too tightly coupled with the versions of your assemblies and whatnot to be considered a stable long-term storage format, and even as you now experience, it can cause problems if you're not doing process-to-process on the same system even.

Comment: Do you know if the original file originated in .NET Framework, .NET Core, or .NET? And which version it was from?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: it was with .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for the link. My error does look the same as the one in the link. But my logic tells me that adding a new culture, while the one for the country where the file originated already exists, will not work. But I may be wrong. Perhaps I can try cloning it but with a new ID.

Comment: @canton7: Thanks for the post. Error looks the same. I have changed my region format to  the one where the file was generated, but still get the same error.